# Best approach to visualise presence/absence of events in multiple groups

Tags: r, data-visualization, radar-chart, circos

I have a dataset where the presence/absence of mutations in 40 particular genes has been recorded comparing normal tissue (e.g. lung tissue) vs a tumour from that tissue (e.g. lung tumor) for twenty tissue types. I am struggling to find the best way to visualise this data.

A subset of the data:

```
Gene    Lung_Normal Lung_Cancer Skin_Normal Skin_Cancer Brain_Normal    Brain_Cancer
Gene_1  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
Gene_2  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
Gene_3  FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
Gene_4  FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
Gene_5  FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
Gene_6  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
Gene_7  FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
Gene_8  FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
Gene_9  FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
Gene_10 FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
```

The key message we want to convey is that while the same 3-4 genes are often mutated in normal tissues, each tumor has many more additional genes mutated and there is more diversity in the tumors. I could just leave it as a table like this, but I would love to find a good way to visualise the information in a clear way.

I would like to try making a figure, like a circus plot, with a single circle with two rings representing all the data. The inner ring would be the normal tissues, the outer ring would be the cancer tissues, with each segment containing the relevant normal tissue on the inner ring and the relevant cancer tissue on the outer ring. Each gene would be colour coded and only shown if mutated. So for all normal tissues the segment would show 2-3 colours for the 2-3 mutated genes, while the outer cancer segment would show many more colour segments, representing the many more mutations.

However I have not found a plotting software that could create such a visualisation. Does anyone know of a way to make a visualisation like this? Even just pointing me towards an R package would be very helpful. I have looked into circos and radar plots but I have not found a package that can make the type of visualisation I have in mind, only showing the events that occur in each case.

If anyone thinks a different kind of visualisation could represent this data please let me know I would be happy to consider alternatives that represent the data with clarity.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be good to see clear examples of exactly what you want, because right now this is pretty subjective—"best" way to do this depends on a lot, including the context, audience, and just people's opinions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I took a stab at it.  Also, I'm not entirely sure from the description above what you want to do with the different types of cells - Lung, Skin, Brain?  If this isn't what you're looking for, perhaps you could post a drawing of what the intended output should look like.

In the picture below, the inner ring is normal cells and the outer ring is cancer cells.  My answer here benefited from [this post](https://biostats.w.uib.no/creating-a-multiple-pie-donut-chart/).

```
## Make the data
tib <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Gene,    ~Lung_Normal, ~Lung_Cancer, ~Skin_Normal, ~Skin_Cancer, ~Brain_Normal,    ~Brain_Cancer,
"Gene_1", TRUE    , TRUE    , TRUE    , TRUE    , TRUE    , TRUE,
"Gene_2",   TRUE,     TRUE,     TRUE,     TRUE,     TRUE,     TRUE, 
"Gene_3", FALSE   , TRUE    , FALSE   , FALSE   , FALSE   , FALSE,
"Gene_4",   FALSE,    FALSE,    FALSE,    FALSE,    FALSE,    FALSE, 
"Gene_5", FALSE   , TRUE    , FALSE   , FALSE   , FALSE   , TRUE,
"Gene_6",   FALSE,    FALSE,    TRUE,     TRUE,     TRUE,     TRUE, 
"Gene_7", FALSE   , FALSE   , FALSE   , TRUE    , FALSE   , FALSE,
"Gene_8",   FALSE,    FALSE,    FALSE,    TRUE,     FALSE,    TRUE, 
"Gene_9", FALSE   , TRUE    , FALSE   , FALSE   , FALSE   , FALSE,
"Gene_10",  FALSE,    FALSE,    FALSE,    TRUE,     FALSE,    TRUE)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

## Re-arrange into long format
tib <- tib %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=-Gene, names_pattern="(.*)_(.*)", names_to=c("type", ".value")) %>%  
  pivot_longer(c(Normal, Cancer), names_to = "diag", values_to="val") %>% 
  # code colors as the gene if it's mutated, otherwise Unmutated
  mutate(f = case_when(val ~ Gene, TRUE ~ "Unmutated")) %>% 
  group_by(Gene, f, diag) %>% 
  summarise(s = n()) %>% 
  mutate(diag = factor(diag, levels=c("Normal", "Cancer")), 
         f = factor(f, levels=c(paste("Gene", c(1,2,6,3,5,7,8,9,10,4), sep="_"), "Unmutated"))) 

library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(tib, aes(x=diag, 
                y = s, 
                fill=f)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  coord_polar("y") + 
  theme_void() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(brewer.pal(9, "Paired"), "gray75")) + 
  labs(fill = "Mutations")
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Here' is what it looks like with the data Allan suggested.  This approach doesn't scale quite as well as the need for having lots of colors is going to make the plot less readable.

```
df <- structure(list(genes = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", 
"Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene9", "Gene10", "Gene11", 
"Gene12", "Gene13", "Gene14", "Gene15", "Gene16", "Gene17", "Gene18", 
"Gene19", "Gene20", "Gene21", "Gene22", "Gene23", "Gene24", "Gene25", 
"Gene26", "Gene27", "Gene28", "Gene29", "Gene30", "Gene31", "Gene32", 
"Gene33", "Gene34", "Gene35", "Gene36", "Gene37", "Gene38", "Gene39", 
"Gene40"), bone_cancer = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), bone_normal = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), brain_cancer = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), brain_normal = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), breast_cancer = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), breast_normal = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), colon_cancer = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), colon_normal = c(FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), kidney_cancer = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                              FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                              TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                              FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                              FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
kidney_normal = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), liver_cancer = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), liver_normal = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), lung_cancer = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
lung_normal = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), prostate_cancer = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), prostate_normal = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), skin_cancer = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), skin_normal = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), thyroid_cancer = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), thyroid_normal = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 40L))
names(df)[1] <- "Gene"
tib <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=-Gene, names_pattern="(.*)_(.*)", names_to=c("type", ".value")) %>%  
  pivot_longer(c(normal, cancer), names_to = "diag", values_to="val") %>% 
  # code colors as the gene if it's mutated, otherwise Unmutated
  mutate(f = case_when(val ~ Gene, TRUE ~ "Unmutated")) %>% 
  group_by(Gene, f, diag) %>% 
  summarise(s = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Gene) %>% 
  mutate(diag = factor(diag, levels=c("normal", "cancer")))
         

levs <- tib %>% 
  dplyr::select(f, s) %>% 
  summarise(pct_mutated = sum(s*(f!= "Unmutated"))/sum(s)) %>% 
  arrange(-pct_mutated)  %>% 
  dplyr::select(Gene) %>% 
  pull()


tib<- tib %>% 
  mutate(f = factor(f, levels=c(levs, "Unmutated")))



library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(tib, aes(x=diag, 
                y = s, 
                fill=f)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  coord_polar("y") + 
  theme_void() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(rainbow(length(levels(tib$f))-1), "gray75")) + 
  labs(fill = "Mutations")
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a nice option Dave - perhaps you could try it with the larger sample data I have put in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron.  I added that to the answer.  I think it doesn't scale as well as the methods mentioned below because the small slices and need for more colors makes it harder to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: wow thank you for this fantastic effort. What you have produced it pretty much what I had in mind. Though I see that the problem I have is with 40 genes it will not read well with the need for so many colours. Still, I will try this approach with my samples to see how it looks. Thank you for the code and explanations.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be a heatmap. You could either do this by faceting cancer vs normal, or adjusting the fill to reflect mutations in cancer only, normal tissue only, both, or neither.

For both of these, it would first be necessary to reshape your data:

**Option 1**

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("tissue", "state"), sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(genes = factor(genes, paste0("Gene", 1:40))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(tissue, genes, fill = value)) + geom_tile(color = "black") +
  facet_grid(.~state) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))
```

[image]

**Option 2**

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("tissue", "state"), sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(genes = factor(genes, paste0("Gene", 1:40))) %>%
  group_by(genes, tissue) %>%
  summarize(mutations = factor(2 + diff(value) + 2 * all(value))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(tissue, genes, fill = mutations)) + geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("Neither", "Cancer only", "Healthy only", "Both"))
```

[image]

For these I have used sample data that should approximate your data structure:

```r
df <- structure(list(genes = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", 
"Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene9", "Gene10", "Gene11", 
"Gene12", "Gene13", "Gene14", "Gene15", "Gene16", "Gene17", "Gene18", 
"Gene19", "Gene20", "Gene21", "Gene22", "Gene23", "Gene24", "Gene25", 
"Gene26", "Gene27", "Gene28", "Gene29", "Gene30", "Gene31", "Gene32", 
"Gene33", "Gene34", "Gene35", "Gene36", "Gene37", "Gene38", "Gene39", 
"Gene40"), bone_cancer = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), bone_normal = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), brain_cancer = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), brain_normal = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), breast_cancer = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), breast_normal = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), colon_cancer = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), colon_normal = c(FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), kidney_cancer = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
    kidney_normal = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), liver_cancer = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), liver_normal = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE), lung_cancer = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
    lung_normal = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), prostate_cancer = c(TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), prostate_normal = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE), skin_cancer = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), skin_normal = c(TRUE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), thyroid_cancer = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE), thyroid_normal = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
40L))
```

Comment: thank you I really like the idea of having cancer only, normal only or both, that might be a good way to get across the main results. Thank you also for the code

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative. Similar to a heat map, but instead using colored points. I also chose to hide the non-mutations since I presume that we are more interested in visualizing where the mutations occur. If the `FALSE` values are also colored, it increases the cognitive load by providing an extra emphasis for our brains to interpret.

```
# Creating the data.
gene_data <- structure(list(Gene = c("Gene_1", "Gene_2", "Gene_3", "Gene_4", 
"Gene_5", "Gene_6", "Gene_7", "Gene_8", "Gene_9", "Gene_10"), 
    Lung_Normal = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Lung_Cancer = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), Skin_Normal = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
    ), Skin_Cancer = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), Brain_Normal = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Brain_Cancer = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Processing the data a little:

```
mutation_data <- gene_data %>%
  pivot_longer(-Gene, values_to = "Mutation") %>%  # making long form
  separate(name, into = c("Type", "Status")) %>% # splitting cell type and cancer status
  mutate(Mutation = as.numeric(Mutation), # cleaning data for plotting
         Type = factor(Type, levels = c("Cancer", "Normal")),
         Gene = factor(Gene, levels = paste0("Gene_", 1:10))) %>% #genes appear in order
  filter(Mutation == 1) # Removing FALSE for cleaner plot
```

Building the plot

```
 ggplot() +
    # plotting all cancer mutations in red
    geom_point(data = mutation_data %>% filter(Status == "Cancer"), 
               aes(x = Type, y = Gene, color = Status),  size = 4)  +
    # plotting all mutations present in normal and cancer in black over top of the red
    geom_point(data = mutation_data %>% filter(Status == "Normal"), 
             aes(x = Type, y = Gene, color = Status), size = 4) +
    # formatting the color scale and legend
    scale_color_manual(name = "Mutation locations", values = c("Cancer" = "Red", "Normal" = "Black"),
                     labels = c("Cancer cells only", "Cancer and normal cells")) +
    # providing title, subtitle, and x label
    labs(title = "Gene mutations in brain, lung, and skin cells",
         subtitle = "Cancer cells vs. normal cells",
         x = "Cell type") +
    theme_bw() # setting a theme I like
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, I like it too. I will also try this approach and see how it looks with all the data compared to the others